# Cookie seems to disappear when page changes

Tags: php, cookies

I have assigned my variable $_SESSION['Username'] with a value from a form $_POST['Username']. This displays fine on the validation page where the system checks it against the database.

(EDIT: I have checked the validation page, and calling  displays the correct value as it should)

I then html redirect using

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=".$_GET['Last']."' />
```

this takes the user back to the page they were on before login,if the details were correct. If not, error message is displayed. This works okay.

However, on the page that the user is redirected to, if i try to

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['Username']; ?>
```

No value is displayed, even though it was set on the previous page.
How can I keep the value in SESSION['Username']?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `session_start()`?

Comment: Can You Share Your Full Code Here..

Comment: Rookie mistake i'm afraid. @heylookltsme was correct. If you could post that as an answer, I will mark it as correct. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: No prob! Posted as an answer. Thanks Harvey :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using `session_start()` to begin a session.